# Modal not repeated in JSTL foreach

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

Within my JSP I have a JSTL foreach which iterates over a list of objects which works overall, but it only outputs the first modal.

The code iterates through each object and outputs it to screen, then when i click to see each modal only the first object works.

Below is the code, any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
<c:forEach items="${listings}" var="listing">
    <div class="l_tile">
        <div class="text">
            <div class="title">
                <c:out value="${listing.type}" /> -
                <c:out value="${listing.category}" />
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <c:out value="${listing.title}" /> (<c:out value="${listing.condition}" />)
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="title">
                <c:out value="${listing.description}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sector">
            <button class="view" id="myBtn">View</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <div class="title">
                <c:out value="${listing.type}" /> -
                <c:out value="${listing.category}" />
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <c:out value="${listing.title}" /> (<c:out value="${listing.condition}" />)
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="title">
                <c:out value="${listing.description}" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <form action="user_servlet" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="user" value=<c:out value="${listing.user}"/>><c:out value="${listing.user}" /></button>
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="comment_servlet" method="post">
                <label for="comment">Comment:</label> 
                <br> 
                <input type="comment" id="comment" name="comment"></input>
                <br> 
                <button type="submit" name="listing" value=<c:out value="${listing.id}"/>>Submit Comment</button>
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button class="select">Select</button>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>

///

<script>
    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("myModal");

    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("view");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: All your modals have the same `id` or `myModal`. How exactly could JavaScript know which one exactly you wanted to open when you only tell it to open the modal with `id` of `myModal`?

Comment: So how would I make it universal / work for every one?

Answer (score 0):

BalusC is right, you can dynamically assign ids to your modals, probably giving it the id of the listing to the modal, something like this:

```
<div id="myModal_' + "${listing.id}" + '" class="modal">
```

Then you, could write a JS function to call onclick of the View button, which would pass the id of the listing as parameter, like this:

```
<button class="view" id="myBtn" onclick="openRelativeModal('${listing.id}')">View</button>
```

And finally you would use this id to open the relative modal, like this:

```
function openRelativeModal(id){$('#myModal_'+id).style.display = "block";}
```

However, overall, having multiple modals, of the same level, in a single page is something you'd rather want to avoid. It would have been a really bad practice to use JSTL to repeat html code to replicate modals. Especially modals that handling more than one can be non-trivial.

In my opinion, what you need to do is to have a single modal and have a JS function to populate it with each listing selected, but I have no idea how your UI is designed, so I can't really make any suggestion on this.